# Get argument for method decorator from a class in MRO

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question regarding getting decorator argument from a class in MRO.

I have a following situation:

```
class Mixin:
    @decorator(params:  list)
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    
class ConcreteClass(Mixin, BaseClass):

    params_for_decorator = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]
```

There is a class called `Mixin` used as mixing in a variety of classes like in example above. What I want to do is to decorate method `foo` in `Mixin` with decorator `decorator` that accepts an argument `params` which is a list with parameters. But I want to have a possibility to pass `params` to decorator from a class where `Mixin` is used (from `ConcreteClass` in this example from `params_for_decorator`), without overriding method `foo` in each and every class.

I can't get my head around this question and I believe it should have a straightforward solution. I can’t change the decorator’s code.
At the moment I am thinking toward implementing a metaclass but it should be something else much simpler.

desirable outcome:

```
class ConcreteClass(Mixin, BaseClass):

    params_for_decorator = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]
            
    #  from  Mixin by MRO
    @decorator(params = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ])
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Comment: The decorator is called when `Mixin` is defined, so AFAIK, you have to use a metaclass for this, but I could be wrong or there might be a better way.

Comment: On the other hand, this could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). What is the decorator actually used for? What does `foo()` actually do?